# nodejs application mysql2 problem when executing INSERT sql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, npm

I tried to create a class for CRUD operation in nodejs with mysql2 module. code here:

```
const SHA256 = require("crypto-js/sha256");

const db = require('../db/mysql/config');

class User {

    constructor(userName, email, password) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = SHA256(password);
    }


    save() {
        db.execute(
            'INSERT INTO user (user_name, email, password) VALUES ( ? , ?, ? )',
            [this.userName, this.email, this.password]);
     }

     static readAll(){
         db.execute('SELECT * FROM user').then((resualt) => {console.log(resualt[0])});
     }
}


module.exports = User;
```

and here the config file:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');


const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: '******',
    database: '******',
    password: '*******'
})

module.exports = pool.promise();
```

but when i try to test save() method by creating and object of User and pass 3 argumant to constructor it shows this error message:

```
(node:2082) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Incorrect arguments to mysqld_stmt_execute
    at PromisePool.execute (/mnt/d/project/fake_invest/node_modules/mysql2/promise.js:343:22)
    at User.save (/mnt/d/project/fake_invest/src/model/user.js:15:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/d/project/fake_invest/src/test.js:4:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
(node:2082) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a
 promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2082) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use a weak high-speed hash for passwords, *especially* not SHA256. Use [Bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) or another **password-specific hash**.

Comment: Tip: Instead of using the MySQL driver, consider using something more full-featured like [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/).

Comment: Not sure what `pool.promise()` is about as usually you just call queries on the pool object directly.

Comment: @tadman it's work on readAll() method. but i use ORMs like sequelize later. thanks.

Comment: Sequelize has an ORM but you don't have to use it. What it does offer is a consistent interface to MySQL, Postgres, SQL Server, and many others, all with a clean design and fully Promise driven.

Comment: Also on any current version of Node you should be able to use `async` functions and `await`. This gets rid of the `then` stuff you have to do.

Comment: Are you using the `mysql2/promise` extension or some other thing that adds the unusual `promise()` function?